# Simulating Destructive High-Speed Collisions

Tags: collision, simulations

I'm at the beginning of some research involving the simulation of space-debris cascades. I understand the various different forces and perturbations that I'm going to be required to account for to propagate these objects through space.

However, I have no idea how to go about modelling such high-speed collisions.

I've seen approaches for collisions on a planetary scale that assume the two objects are merely made up of many particles interacting purely gravitationally, indicating that frictional forces are somewhat negligible in such a scenario. However,  given the objects that I'd be working with are on the order of 10-10000kgs, I don't think that's a viable approach.

There are many papers that seem to gloss over this part of their research, so I assume there's some reasonably standard approach to this, I just can't seem to find it...

So, what approaches are there for modelling the outcome of two objects destructively colliding at tens of kilometres per second?

Ideally, I want to be able to specify the mass, shape, and velocity of the input objects, and then get a list of the mass, shape, and velocity of the resulting debris.

Note: I'm not looking for you to give me an exact algorithm, that would be way too much work. More to suggest viable approaches on which I can build (similar to the example I've given), and maybe what the limitations of each approach are.

Comment: What are your simplifying assumptions? On its face this seems like a life's work for a whole team of experts, starting from the hard-earned results of multiple other whole teams of experts...

Comment: Well, that’s part of the question, if you take my example, the whole thing is simplified by assuming that gravity is the only non-negligible force and treating the planet as a bunch of individual particles. Can you do something similar for smaller objects and assume that they’re a bunch of particles held together by XYZ instead? I’m assuming there are some fairly well-understood approaches to this because there are lots of papers that just completely gloss over how they modelled the actual collisions

Comment: During the collision, some energy is absorbed deforming the parts and shearing material off which causes heat. So the effects can be glossed over when considering _inelastic_ collisions as energy is lost with these conditions.

Comment: If you look at some high-speed collision videos on youtube you will realize that the resulting projectiles cannot be analytically predicted but stochastically. There is just too much chaos entropy introduced to know _excactly_ what is going to happen.